# R: ada: how to use pairs on a dataframe with categorical descriptors?

Tags: r, machine-learning

I'm using the `ada` package for classification where the descriptor variables are both `categoric` and `numeric`. This leads to a problem when calling the `pairs` function. Below is an example which illustrates my problem:

```
require(rpart)
require(ada)

data(car90, package = "rpart")
target = "Country"
input = setdiff(names(car90), target)

# ada only works with two distinct responses
car90 = car90[car90$Country %in% c("USA", "Japan/USA"), ] 

# remove surplus factor levels
car90$Country = as.character(car90$Country) 

adaCar90 = ada(car90[, input], car90[, target])
pairs(adaCar90, car90[, input], vars = 32:33)

# Error in pairs.default(as.matrix(rbind(train.data, test.x))[, vars],   
# lower.panel = panel.low,  :  non-numeric argument to 'pairs'
```

Selecting only `numeric` descriptors using the `vars` argument of the `pairs` function doesn't seem to resolve matters. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the maintainer of the `ada` package didn't anticipate your specific use case. The very last line of `ada:::pairs.ada` reads:

```
pairs(as.matrix(rbind(train.data, test.x))[, vars], lower.panel = panel.low, 
    upper.panel = panel.up)
```

The problem lies in where `[, vars]` has been placed. The code binds together `train.data` and `test.x`, then turns the whole thing into a matrix, and then subsets. Because your train.data contains a bunch of non-numeric columns, `as.matrix` returns a character matrix. If you change the last line to this:

```
pairs(as.matrix(rbind(train.data, test.x)[, vars]), lower.panel = panel.low, 
    upper.panel = panel.up)
```

then `as.matrix` is only called on the subset that contains numeric data, and the function works.

**EDIT**

I think what I suggested above is a good long-term solution, but there could be an easier short-term fix: pass only those columns of your training data that you will need for the graph instead of using the `vars` option. That way, only numeric data is ever passed to that final line of code. That would probably get you your graphs without you needing to hack the function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer SchaunW. Regarding the `train.data` argument of the `pairs` function, the `ada` manual says: *the 'data.frame' of the original data used to train the classifier*. Thus I don't know if the short-term fix would be possible. I have tried it: `num = names(which(sapply(car90[, input], is.numeric))); pairs(adaCar90, car90[, num])` and an error is still produced. I could of course be implementing your solution incorrectly. I'm going to check out the alternate solution i.e. the hack, now. Thanks.